# Como utilizar text_field via ajax

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Estou tentando chamar via ajax uma função num campo text_field, tentei de duas formas:
1 - Da erro de undefined method remote_function.

```
<%= f.text_field(:data, class: "form-control", :remote => true, :onchange=>remote_function(:url=>{:action=>"fetch_duration"})) %>
```

2 - Da erro de Sintase

```
<%= f.text_field(:data, class: "form-control", :remote => true, :onchange=> {:url=>{:action=>"fetch_duration"}}) %>
```

Alguém tem algum exemplo, ou link que possa me ajudar?

Answer (score 0):

Acho que você tem que passar o código JS para String para ele ser executado, ou uma chamada de função javascript que você implementou.